# Dubai airport enquiries

Tags: air-travel, transit-visas, uae

I am traveling to Bangladesh from the UK in December and I have transit of 4.5 hours in the Dubai airport. Within this time, I have to go from terminal 3 to terminal 2. Will I be able to do this without a visa?

If I have to collect my luggage, do I need to leave the terminal and re-enter? If so, will I be able to do that without a visa? How can I book a shuttle bus for me in advance?

Comment: What is your citizenship, and how are your flights booked (regarding your baggage transfer)?

Comment: I have Bangladeshi citizenship. I will start my journey with virgin Atlantic from uk to Dubai. Virgin Atlantic said I have to carry my own luggage after I reach Dubai airport. They will be no longer responsible for carrying luggage to next plane.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Timatic](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/vendors/default.aspx?i=TIMATIC), you are able to transit without a visa because you hold a confirmed onward ticket. The maximum transit time allowed is 24 hours.
Timatic is used by airlines to verify passengers travel document requirements for their destination and any transit.

On arrival in Dubai International Airport, there are dedicated transfer desks from which to get your boarding pass for your onward flight. The transfer desks in Terminal 3 are at Gates A, B and C.

You don't mention your carrier between Dubai and Bangladesh, so here are the [airport directions on how to move between terminals](http://www.dubaiairports.ae/before-you-fly/procedures/flight-connections).

> When connecting between A, B or C Gates, all the gates are within walking distance. The only exceptions are the A Gates. For these you take the airport train.
>
> If you are connecting to or from F Gates (located across the tarmac), your airline will tell you what to do. Services include free shuttle buses, Marhaba service and public transport.
>
> If you’re transferring to or from certain flydubai flights from Terminal 2, you can use the dedicated transfer service. For all other flights transferring through Terminal 2, you should proceed through Arrivals to collect your baggage at Baggage Reclaim, and then transfer to your connecting terminal using public or private transport.

The airport shuttles don't have a pre-booking option; the journey time between Terminal 3 and Terminal 2 is about 30 minutes.

[Marhaba is a service](http://www.marhabaservices.com/) that can arrange transportation, and other, services which can be booked in advance.

Before arranging for transportation between Terminals 3 and 2, you should first check your onward airline's DXB information, as many provide dedicated shuttle services for their passengers.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are on two separate tickets; or that Virgin Atlantic doesn't have rights to book your luggage through to your connecting flight from Dubai to Dhaka.

If you have to collect your luggage, you will have to either:

1. Get a transit visa for Dubai.
2. Pay for the Marhaba service to collect the bags on your behalf.

For transferring between the two terminals:

1. If you do not have a boarding pass for your Dubai - Dhaka flight; and you cannot get it issued from the airside transfers desks; then you will need a visa to exit immigration, and then check-in as a normal passenger from Dubai.
2. If you are given both boarding passes when you check in to your Virgin Atlantic flight; then you can follow the transit/transfer arrows (arrange for or collect your luggage) and then proceed to Terminal 2 via the inter-terminal bus (check with your airline that is taking you from Dubai to Dhaka for the specifics).